# Where can I find the AEON pruning branch?

Tags: aeon, pruning

Very recently [smooth_xmr](https://np.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/5vu675/aeon_just_got_an_update/de6oc0v) said:

> You might try the experimental pruning branch, which has been updated to 0.9.7.1 (I don't have the link for the instructions, maybe someone else knows it?)

The download link on [Aeon.cash](http://www.aeon.cash/) leads to the GitHub [release page](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/releases) but I cannot seem to locate the pruning branch.

Where can I find the newly updated pruning branch referenced by Smooth?

Does it have install instructions available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the post indicated the pruning branch is still considered experimental. Therefore it resides in another GitHub repository [found here](https://github.com/iamsmooth/aeon/tree/light-node). I have included a summary of the [instructions smooth provided](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.msg12272943#msg12272943) upon releasing the pruning branch which should still be accurate today

Clone from GitHub:

> git clone https://github.com/iamsmooth/aeon light-node
>   cd light-node
>   git checkout light-node

Compile:

> make

Copy your blockchain.bin file to blockchain-pruned.bin in the same location. Save the unpruned copy as a backup and in case you experience problems with the pruning branch.

Start your node with `--pruning` option. Then exit to save the pruning branch and reset RAM. Then start with `--pruning` again and run as normal.